# Custom Domain With Heroku with a CNAME record - not working

Tags: heroku, dns, cross-domain, dreamhost

I used the [heroku guide to setting up a custom domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) to set up a custom domain for a Heroku app, however, the custom CNAME record I set up at Dreamhost isn't working correctly. The website for my app (myappname.com) shows the Heroku page that says "There's nothing here, yet".

Here's what I used per the Heroku guide:

CNAME record at Dreamhost:

- record: www
- type: CNAME
- Value: myappname.com.herokudns.com

In my Heroku settings this is what shows as the target DNS:

> myappname.com.herokudns.com

This is my first time setting up a custom domain with Heroku so I'm not sure whats going wrong. I looked at all of the similar questions here and read some guides online too. Should I change the DNS record to "myappname.heroku.com"?

I should note the heroku app is on the free tier so there is no SSL.

Comment: And which is the domain name at Heroku? (to the left of target DNS)

Comment: Show the true name involved, without useless obfuscation, if you want relevant help.

Comment: Pablo, the domain name in the heroku settings is : myappname.com

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, if anyone else makes the same silly mistake I made, make sure your DNS target at Heroku includes the correct subdomain ('www' in this case).